# How to repeat TryParse until success in F#?

Tags: while-loop, f#, tryparse

Sorry for dumb question, but I'm perplexed a bit.

In C# I can idiomatically do the following:

```
int result = 0;
while (!Int32.TryParse(someString, out result))
{
    ...
}
```

In F# I have two options for Try*DoSomething* pattern.
It's either

```
let (isSuccess, result) = Int32.TryParse someString
```

or

```
let result = ref 0
let isSuccess = Int32.TryParse("23", result)
```

I can do `while not Int32.TryParse("23", result) do ...` but have no idea whether the same is achievable with the first variant.

P.S. Sure, tail recursion is also feasible here, but I'm interested in using `while` construct.

Comment: I think you already answered your question :) You can use the second variant with `while` or the first variant with recursion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do :

```
while (not (fst (Int32.TryParse someString))) do
  printfn "in while loop. It's not an Int32." ;
  someString <- Console.ReadLine();
```

or (if you care about the parsed result) :

```
while 
   let (isSuccess, result) = Int32.TryParse someString in
   not isSuccess do
       printfn "in while loop. It's not an Int32 ; it is %A" result;
       someString <- Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: If you don't need the result you can also do: `Int32.TryParse "1" |> fst |> not`

Comment: By the way, the example above still requires a mutable variable in an outer scope, if result is needed after `while` is finished.

Comment: @voroninp : Sure. I only put the while block in my snippet.